# How to use chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML()?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, parsing, google-chrome-extension, mhtml

I am building a chrome extension that will parse through the HTML of whatever website the user is viewing for metadata.

I am super new at using the chrome API, and I am trying to figure out how to use chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML(object details, function details). These parameters are pretty confusing to me.... I was trying to use http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageCapture but I haven't figured it out yet.

How do i assign the MHTML to a variable so that I can begin parsing?

Comment: Why would you want to do it this way? Inject a content script, parse `document` as you wish.

Comment: @Xan, thanks for the input! I am simply trying to pull metadata from webpage using A Google Chrome extensions. I am not sure the best way to go about it. I am open to exploring different solutions for this.

Comment: Read the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) and try using content scripts.

Answer (score 1):

```js
chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML({ tabId: tab.id }, async (blob) => {
    const content = await blob.text();
    const url = "data:application/x-mimearchive;base64," + btoa(content);
    chrome.downloads.download({
        url,
        filename: 'filename.mhtml'
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, it answers the question: 'How to use chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML()?'